# Replace all in a string except of two indexes

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have an input like this:
`$input="12050301000000000000";`

I am trying to use `preg_replace` to change every thing in my input to `0` except of two chars referenced by their indexes.

For example I want to replace everything except of the first and the second characters to 0.

I tried this:

```
$input="02050301000000000000";
$index1=0;
$index2=1;
$output= preg_replace('/(?!^'.$index1.')/', '0', $input);
```

Comment: Why not a simpler: `$output = str_repeat('0',strlen($input)); $output[$index1] = $input[$index1]; $output[$index2] = $input[$index2];`, which would be far easier to read and understand than a regexp

Comment: Can't get a nicer answer than that and that too in a comment!

Comment: @MarkBaker I like your answer, can you post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Please post a clear sample of the **input** and desired **output**.

Answer (score 0):

```
function replace($string, $replace) {
    $args = func_get_args();
    $string = array_shift($args);
    $replace = array_shift($args);
    $len = strlen($string);
    $i = 0;
    $result = '';
    while($i < $len) {
        $result .= !in_array($i, $args) ? $replace : $string[$i];
        $i++;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

The function accept an arbitrary number of indexes (int) after $string and $replace

```
$input="12050301000000000000";
echo $input;
echo '<br>';
echo replace($input, 'a', 1, 3, 5, 7);
```

Answer (score 0):

it is work for me

```
$input="02050301000000000000";
$index1=0;
$output = preg_replace("/[^".$index1."+?!^]/", '0', $input );
```

Thank you..

Comment: if use preg_replace("/[^".$index1."+?!^]/", '8', $input );  it will be 08080808000000000000 replace without replace zero thank you..

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you want to replace 1 and 3 indexed values 2 and 5:

```js
$string = '02050301000000000000';
$patterns = array();
$patterns[1] = '/2/';
$patterns[3] = '/5/';
$replacements = array();
$replacements[1] = '0';
$replacements[3] = '0';
$output = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
var_dump($output);
```

**Output:**
2 and 5 are replaced with 0.

```js
string(20) "00000301000000000000"
```

For more details have a look on using indexed array in preg_replace:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php